# Sichuan food in Xi'an

Tags: food-and-drink, china, restaurants, xian

Can I find Sichuan food in Xi'an, China? As an English speaker, how can I ensure I am getting authentic food on the menu (is there a "omakase" equivalent)? I don't care much for fancy, or touristy, places - hole in the wall is fine, and would probably be a great story.

Comment: From the ease of finding Xi'an food in Kunming and the greater reputation Sichuan cuisine enjoys, I'm sure there are very many places in Xi'an. We cannot give recommendations here if it turns out not to be specialized as I expect, but we can hopefully get you an answer telling you how to find some places.

Comment: I would say getting an answer to your other question will go a long way to answering this one.

Comment: Can I ask why you're looking specifically for Sichuanese food?  Xi'an is in Shaanxi, not Sichuan, and has its own cuisine.

Comment: @jpatokal: Would you question people looking for Chinese food in San Francisco or Indian food in London? Sichuanese food is a famous cuisine available all over the place, even if you won't be able to make it to Sichuan you can still seek it.

Comment: I'd question somebody looking for deep dish pizza in New York - I'm sure you can find it, but odds are the person asking is probably thinking Chicago.

Comment: jpatokal: I understand it's not the right area, I just enjoy Sichuan and figure I can get better Sichuan food in Xi'an than in San Francisco.

Comment: I have replaced subjective constructs like "best" with possible ones like "authentic" and wonder if the question can be reopened it is current form.

Answer (score 3):

I stuck the characters for restaurant review, Sichuan and Xian (西安) into Baidu and got some results.

Note that genuine typical Sichuan (四川) food (in my experience) may not appeal to Westerners all that much. Often it is swimming in fiery chili oil and has other odd characteristics.

For example:-
http://www.dianping.com/shop/3988318
http://www.dianping.com/shop/550746

[image]

Comment: I'm a westerner and I know I'm not alone in loving Sichuan food. The more authentic the better, chilli, Sichuan pepper, oil. Better than the bland stuff that passes for "Chinese food" we often have to settle for at home. Other westerners I met in China who had spent time in Sichuan were always moaning about how they couldn't get proper Sichuan food even in other parts of China!

Comment: Glad you like it. I find that quantity of oil a bit much, and a shock to the digestive system (don't ask) until you get used to it.

Comment: Chinese usually leave most of the soup, oil, sauce, gravy, etc uneaten in dishes that are high in liquids. The high oil content bothered me in their instant noodles but not in restaurant dishes.